# Inner Joining Multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, join

I Have three tables in my database
users , posts and comments.

Their Structure is as follow :

```
**users** : 
user_id , user_name
**posts**: 
post_id , post_content, user_id
**comments** :
comment_id , comment_content , post_id, user_id
```

now i want to fetch data from these three tables using join in a following way : 
comment_id, comment_content, user_id, user_name, post_id
can anyone plz tell me  that how this can be done ? 
I Shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple `JOIN`.

Try this:

```
select c.comment_id,
    c.comment_content,
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    c.post_id
from comments c
join users u on u.user_id = c.user_id;
```

If you need columns from posts table too, join it:

```
select c.comment_id,
    c.comment_content,
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    p.post_id,
    p.post_content
from comments c
join users u on u.user_id = c.user_id
join posts p on c.post_id = p.post_id;
```

Comment: its only returning one comment for one post ... i want to fetch all comments for particular post...
like i want to fetch all comments  that are posted on post_id 157

Comment: yes i had already tried this one but this query fetches all comments for any post and attaches the user_id of that post as user_id of comment on all comments on that post ... is there anyway to show screen shot here in comments ? so that i can share screen-shots with you ?

Comment: @Shehzad  - Is there any reason you unaccepted the answer please?

Comment: please excuse me i am really very confused .... now i am testing very carefully as comments are getting mixed 
would you mind giving me some time please so that i can test query more efficiently ?

Comment: @gurV- now i have tested both quries and got the limitations of my query ... :-) if i want to fetch something other than p_id i can't use that query ...
your solution is perfectly working efficiently i can fetch anything from the three tables ... thank you so much and do excuse me as i was badly confused

Comment: @Shehzad - No worries. Happens to all of us at some point. :-)